# Trying to upload app get "Icon specified in info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to upload a new app I maid to the itunes store.
I'm getting the following error
"Icon specified in info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper
I have added the icons by dragging on dropping them summery screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the icon file is added in the **Copy Bundle Resources** build phase.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for helping me out on thsi, Ted